# how to update status column on user login in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5.4

currently i am working on my laravel project. Its a social networking base website and i want to update the **status column** from **0** to **1** when user login. On that point i am able to check my friends status which are online

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`lastName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`displayName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`dob` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`gender` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`remember_token` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this....

```
if(Auth::user()->status==0)
{
   Auth::user()->update(['status'=>1]);
}
```

Comment: Where you want to change your status

Comment: for example  in Home controller index method before return redirect('dashboard');

Comment: but tell me one thing on logout i want to update it on 0 again. and there is no controller for logout in laravel 5. i am using this Rout but there is controller
   `Route::any('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');`

Comment: In Auth Controller you can see *use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers* open this trait you can see another trait *use AuthenticateUsers* open that trait now finally you can see getLogout method and put  code inside that method but this time you should check reverse condition